# socket.io initiate message from server side

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'd like to initiate a message from server to the available clients using socket.io.
All the examples I could find are waiting for the client to connect (using the 'connected' event) and respond to that event with a message, like:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://domain.com');
socket.on('connect', function () {
  // socket connected
  socket.emit('server custom event', { my: 'data' });
});
```

I'd like to initiate sending a message to whoever clients connected when a specific event happens at the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send a message to all connected clients you must use one of those two (they are equivalent)

```
io.sockets.emit('message', data);
io.emit('message', data);
```

You can read more on that [here](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/)